# Using SharedPreferences with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I have problem with loading data from `SharedPreferences` with `Gson`.
I have `ArrayLists` of objects of my `Product` class. I want to save them, and then to load them. Here is my `loadList` method:

```java
    public void loadList(ArrayList list, String name){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(name, null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>() {}.getType();
        list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        //Toast.makeText(this, ""+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(list == null){
            list = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

When I use this method without parameter, everything is fine. But when I try to send my `ArrayList` as a parameter, it doesn't work and list is underscored.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: can you also provide json here?

Comment: I get no error. when I start my Activity it turns off

Comment: its due to parsing exception. :)

Comment: how sould i deal with it?

Comment: Why would you even pass array list while accessing your saved list?

Comment: because I have 10 lists and I want to use one loadList() method

Comment: just check, whether you are getting anything in json or not from shared pref.

Answer (score -1):

So lets say you one Json file like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "product1",
    "itemNumber": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "product2",
    "itemNumber": "456"
  }
]
```

And you want parse this json you need to have one model class, in your case you have Product:

```
data class Product(val name: String, val itemNumber: String)
```

In this example I have kept predefine json file inside assets folder but in your case you are reading it from SharedPreference. Which is I think causing the issue. Because after successful read from json I am able to parse json in required List.

You can refer below method, which can give you some idea about parsing.

```
void parseGson() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("input.json"); //file name placed in assets folder
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Product>>() {}.getType();
    List<Product> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: [Product(name=product1, itemNumber=123), Product(name=product2, itemNumber=456)]
```

If you want more help, you need to provide json text and code of Product model. I hope it will help you in resolving your issue.

Comment: thanks for your help but I tried something different. I've made my loadList() method return ArrayList<Product> and now it works. but honestly, I don't know why